# Rails 3 detect request coming from mobile clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

My app needs to serve up a mobile vs. web layout depending on the request's origin. I need to support all the major mobile client front-ends like iPhone, Android, Blackberry, etc. What's the simplest way to detect this in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is parse **request.user_agent** by RegEx */Mobile|webOS/*.
Mobile/Full version variable can be saved into session, and helper will be useful to include mobile CSS:

```
#controller
def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end

helper_method :mobile_device?


#layout
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mobile' if mobile_device? %>
```

[Railscasts 199](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) is a step-by-step guide for you.

Answer (score 7):

It will return User Agent.

```
request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|Blackberry|Android/ # OR WHATEVER
```