# rails how to check if request is coming from mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile-safari, httprequest, user-agent, mobile-browser

I was wondering if there was a way to check if a http request is coming from a mobile application or not.  I see plenty of guides on how to check if a http request is coming from a mobile browser, but not from mobile applications (iPhone/iPad apps specifically).

I'm using Rails version 4.0.3 if that information helps in any way.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7069136/1801147

Comment: A good strategy with this sort of thing is to log out all the headers with the request from your mobile.  You should see something stand out - the UserAgent header in this case.